# Nesting One Package in Another (Cournot Duopoly with neural network package)

Tags: packages

I am writing a 2-firm (Cournot Duopoly) game, where both players learn to optimise their long-term rewards by a neural network (the input is the price the firm sets, the output is the estimated reward). The environment I wrote for the neural network learning package works as follows:

```
BeginPackage[ "SingleDeepLearning`"]

SingleDeepLearning::usage = 
     "Implement Deep Learning with only firm input"

Begin[ "Private`"]

SingleDeepLearning[z_]:=
     Module[
          {relu,myfirmq,otherfirmq},

          ...(neural network code)

     ]

     End[]

EndPackage[]
```

Then the actual playoff of the firm is as follows (for example, I will let them play 1000 rounds)

```
BeginPackage[ "SingleLearning`"]

SingleLearning::usage = 
     "Both firms playing Cournot Duopoly game with single input deep learning"

Begin[ "Private`"]

SingleLearning[z_]:=
     Module[
          {firm1hiddenlayer1output,firm1hiddenlayer2output,firm1outputlayeroutput,
          firm2hiddenlayer1output,firm2hiddenlayer2output,firm2outputlayeroutput},

          ...(game code)

          firm1z=Join[...];
          firm2z=Join[...];

          simfirm1=NestList[SingleDeepLearning[#]&,firm1z,20];
          simfirm2=NestList[SingleDeepLearning[#]&,firm2z,20];

          takesimfirm1=Part[simfirm1,20];
          takesimfirm2=Part[simfirm2,20];

          firm1neuralnetwork=Take[takesimfirm1,{4,33}]
          firm2neuralnetwork=Take[takesimfirm2,{4,33}]
          ...(rest of game code)

     ]

     End[]

EndPackage[]
```

The error message comes out similar to "Take::take: Cannot take positions 4 through 33 in Private'SingleDeepLearning[Private'SingleDeepLearning[Private'SingleDeepLearning[<<1>>]]]".

However, when I run the codes in the SingleLearning package line by line, and repeat a number of times, there are no errors.

Does the SingleLearning package have errors in how it calls the neural network developed in SingleDeepLearning package?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you're missing is calling Needs with BeginPackage, i.e.

```
BeginPackage["SingleLearning`", {"SingleDeepLearning`"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your help! I think it works, right now I'm debugging a different error, but it seems the problem is solved!